# base_url() use in ckeditor config.js file

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

how we can use base url in js file using codeigniter

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    // ...
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
// ...
};
```

use base_url here

```
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = base_url().'/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
```

### but not work base_url

Answer (score 1):

You can't call php function inside javascript code like this.

If your javascript is inside your view you can do it like this

```
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = <?php echo base_url(); ?>.'/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
```

But if your javascript code is on a separate .js file, just use javascript

```
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
```

Eventually, you can declare in your view.php

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

And call it in your js

```
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = baseUrl + '/codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP in javascript like that.

Try `<?=base_url('codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images)?>` or `<?php echo base_url('codeigniter/kpminerals/support/editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images'); ?>`

Is /codeigniter/ part of your base url in your config.php? If so remove it from the above.

Answer (score 0):

this is write work in js file

```
var base_url = window.location;
    // ...
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = base_url+'editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = base_url+'editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = base_url+'editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = base_url+'editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = base_url+'editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = base_url+'editor/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    // ...
```